# Firebase redirect to same path name

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

How can I add a script or something similar in Firebase JSON file to redirect to a different domain but with the same path.

For example: my users are currently visiting mydomain.com/help/page_id_1

Here page_id_1 is dynamic id's.

I want to redirect to support.mydomain.com/help/page_id_1

Can I do this as a redirect in firebase.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! It'd look like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [{
      "source": "/help/:page",
      "destination": "https://support.mydomain.com/help/:page",
      "type": 301
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this result in a redirect loop if the destination domain is pointed to the same firebase config?  For example if we are redirecting example.com/:page to www.example.com/:page which are both pointed at the firebase installation?

Comment: Yes, most likely.